# I cant get two areas of content to float beside each other

Tags: html, css

I can't make two areas of content float beside each other without disrupting my container. I have the first area cued to float:left but when I cue float:right to content area 2 my container doesn't work anymore.

The object does float right but the container disappears.

Here is my website http://aasdsafasdf.weebly.com/ (I'm in the very early stages)

```
#container {
width: 1100px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #ffffff;
}


#content {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 710px;
}

#content2 {
float: right;
height: auto;
width: 350px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some markup errors on your page (notice the `</script>` tag after one of your links to a stylesheet?) but just set your container to hide overflow:

```
#container {
   width: 1100px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: #ffffff;
   overflow:hidden
}
#content2 {
   height: auto;
   width: 350px;
   float:right;
}
```

That should fix the issue. But make sure you fix up your code... it has a variety of issues now: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Faasdsafasdf.weebly.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks I tried to clean up all the issues but your fix didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
width: 1100px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #ffffff;
}


#content {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 710px;
display: block;
}

#content2 {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 350px;
display: block;
}
```

You want both content div's to float left and be display:block;, then they will push up against the one to its left.